# Call a function inside Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, coffeescript, long-polling

I'm having a problem, I can't make a loop inside this code:

```
    class ProductsPager
      constructor: ->
        this.waitformsg()
      waitformsg: =>
        alert 'begin'
        $.ajax
          type: "GET"
          url: "http://0.0.0.0:3000/live/index.json"
          async: true
          cache: false
          timeout: 1000
          success: (data) ->
            alert data
          error: (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            alert "end"
            waitformsg()setTimeout "waitformsg()", 0
```

The two arlerts are for debugging. It displays me only one time of each: "*begin*", and right after "*end*" and nothing else.
I have concluded that the last line is wrong and I need to find a way to call a method inside Ajax.
I have tried to replace `setTimeout "waitformsg()", 0` by `this.waitformsg()` or even `waitformsg()` but it still doesn't work.

I would like to display infinite "alerts" untill the right conditions to succeed are gathered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two:

```
waitformsg()
setTimeout waitformsg, 0
```

won't work because there is no `waitformsg` function in scope.

This:

```
setTimeout "waitformsg()", 0
```

won't work because there is no *global* function called `waitformsg`, the string form of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) executes the string in the global context. I'd recommend that you forget that `setTimeout` even has a string form.

You should bind the callbacks to the current context using a [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow):

```
waitformsg: =>
  alert 'begin'
  $.ajax
    #...
    error: (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) =>
      alert "end"
      @waitformsg()
```

And if you want the error handler to wait a second before trying again:

```
setTimeout @waitformsg, 1000
```

The `waitformsg` method will run in the correct context because you defined it as a bound function.

A couple more things while I'm here:

1. Using `@` is more idiomatic in CoffeeScript than using `this` so your constructor should be:

   ```
   constructor: ->
     @waitformsg()
   ```
2. jQuery's `async:true` flag for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has been deprecated so you should stop using it. `async:true` is also a nasty thing to do to your users (especially in a loop) so again, you should stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with CoffeeScript much, so here's how you would do it in Javascript:

```
waitformsg: function() {
    var self = this;

    ...
    ...

    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.waitformsg();
    };
};
```

When you simply call `waitformsg()`, you're basically calling `window.waitformsg()`. Since this doesn't exist, your code doesn't work. You cannot use `this`, because the callback is asynchronous and so the value of `this` is pretty much whatever jQuery sets it to (if it sets it at all) when the `error` callback is called. So you need to maintain a reference to `this` that gets passed down into the close as well and you can do this by creating a new variable in the local scope of the function and assigning `this` to that variable (in this case, I've called that new variable `self`). Then you can call `self.waitformsg();`.